# Change links in wordpress template without creating a table in database

Tags: php, database, wordpress

I have a wordpress template which have some static content.
in fact the index page has a page template and its all static and have no control from wordpress.but using header and footer.
I want to change static links in this page using admin panel.
How to change this static links from wordpress panel without using a database to store this links? 
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to edit theme's files. Use Wordpress editor for this.

**UPDATE**

Install the plugin for managing options. For example, [WP Options Editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-options-editor/screenshots/)

In your template replace the code that should be customizable with the

```
get_option('your_option_name');
```

Comment: hi.thx for your answer.but i want to create a menu for this using actions in admin area

Comment: Create a simple plugin that use get_option and set_option.

Comment: look for example i have this block in my page :

Comment: I want to change this link form wordpress admin panel

Comment: im developing that site for a person who cant edit anything.what he need is a panel.and i dont know how to edit links without store them in a database . . .

Comment: thank you.that what exactly what i want.I searched on get option that you said.and there is a way to add to the database without using queries and that exactly what i want.my repitution is low to like youe answer but i liked it